# Is flask compatible with pygame

Tags: python, flask, pygame

Hi ive been developing some games in pygame and am looking to put them on a website for my friends to play, Ive been told that flask is the way for setting up a python website and then hosting on python anywhere, but so far I havent seen any guides on using pygame with flask and am unsure if the games will work with flask ie will it be able to display the pygame screen on the website as a normal browser game would

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work like that.

Pygame doesn't have a browser "backend", it's purely for desktop games.

Comment: I have the game as an exe as well would it be possible to run this on a flask based website, if not I know some java script and was wondering also if I could possibly run the exe on a javascript based website

Comment: But pygame community edition (pygame-ce) has one. Though If you only have an exe ( no source code at all ) then you should look for a web pc emulator like those you can find on http://copy.sh/v86/

Answer (score 0):

You can publish pygame-ce (community edition) games on Web
within an iframe you can make with flask.

There's a tool called pygbag ( python3 -m pip install --user pygbag) to help deploying games on website.

Be aware that you need a SSL certificate for your site or some pygame-ce functions won't work ( multiplayer audio recording, camera).

You can see some already published with that iframe configuration here https://itch.io/c/2563651/pygame-wasm